# Capture multiline, multi-group to Powershell variables

Tags: regex, powershell, multiline

Ideally, I would like to create an object from ipconfig that allows us to drilldown to each adapter's attributes like this: $ip.$lan.$mac for the lan adapter's mac address.

To start, I would like to develop a way to capture these 3 groups (adapter type, adapter name, adapter attributes) per adapter match into Powershell variables (objects are preferred):  https://regex101.com/r/wZ3sV1/1

Here are some ideas to capture three parts of the Ethernet adapter section, but they are only capturing "Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:":

```
$ip = ipconfig /all

$ip_lan = $ip | Select-String -pattern "(Ethernet [^a]*adapter) (Local[^:]+):\s*(([^\n]+\n)*)" -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | ForEach-Object {$_.Value}

$regex_lan = [regex]"(Ethernet [^a]*adapter) (Local[^:]+):\n*(( +[^\n]+\n)*)"
$regex_lan.Matches($ip)
$regex_lan.Matches($ip).value
```

Also, is there a way to capture the name of the group extraction like this?:

```
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
```

becomes Description = Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

Comment: I am liking this, but the third group is not capturing: [regex]::Match($ip,"(Ethernet [^a]*adapter) (Local[^:]+):\n*(( +[^\n]+\n)*)").captures.groups[1].value
$regex_lan = [regex]::Match($ip,"(Ethernet [^a]*adapter) (Local[^:]+):\n*(( +[^\n]+\n)*)")

Comment: $ip is created by: $ip = ipconfig /all

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly what you'd like the objects created from the captured data to look like?

Comment: ip = 192.168.0.1, etc.  I just want the raw data assigned to relevant field names.  Object is preferred, but I can create the object from the variables easily enough, I expect.

Comment: Should we be focusing at all on making ipconfig /all into an object, or is it too difficult to parse the data that it returns into an object?

Comment: Powershell was made to work with objects. I think part of the problem is that you're not very clear about the objective.  There is a lot of data in that output, and "ip = 192.168.0.1, etc." is a very poor explanation of what you'd like the resulting object to look like, or even whether you'd want it parsed into one object for the entire configuration or one object per adapter.

Comment: mjolinor, thank you for the feedback.  I'll admit that I don't understand objects as well as I like, but the structure of ipconfig seemed rather intuitive to me.  It looks like an ipconfig object with several adapter child objects.  So the structure, as I imagine it, would look like: $ip.$lan.$mac to get the mac address of the lan adapter in the ipconfig object.  Please correct my understanding of objects or help me to clarify the goal further, as needed.  I have looked around a lot and not seen any posts illuminate how to do this.  One issue may be variability in adapter names and numbers.

Comment: You're calling out specific adapter sections of the IPConfig output for data extraction, but not any of the information in that first header section that includes things like the Host Name. This implies an objective of creating a collection of adapter objects, rather than a single object for the entire configuration that has the adapter collection as a property.

Comment: mjolinor, you are correct that my original plan was to pull specific adapters as separate objects.  And learning how to do that alone would be immensely valuable.  But as I see the power of objects in Powershell, I wonder if creating adapter objects under an ipconfig object is possible.  Do you know how to do either?

Comment: I left an answer with some regex examples.  Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question.  But rather than parsing the output of `ipconfig` with Regex.  You could instead use `Get-NetIPConfiguration` to get a powershell object that is easier to deal with.

```
PS> $ip = Get-NetIPConfiguration
PS> $ip

InterfaceAlias       : Ethernet
InterfaceIndex       : 12
InterfaceDescription : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM
NetProfile.Name      : xyz.com
IPv4Address          : 10.20.102.162
IPv6DefaultGateway   :
IPv4DefaultGateway   : 10.20.102.1
DNSServer            : 10.20.100.9
                       10.20.100.11
                       10.20.100.13

PS> $ip.IPv4Address

IPAddress         : 10.20.102.162
InterfaceIndex    : 12
InterfaceAlias    : Ethernet
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 23
PrefixOrigin      : Dhcp
SuffixOrigin      : Dhcp
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : 05:16:53
PreferredLifetime : 05:16:53
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore
PSComputerName    :
```

Thus you can do the following to get the values you are looking to acquire.

```
$ip.InterfaceAlias
$ip.InterfaceDescription
$ip.IPv4Address.IPAddress
```

To get the MAC the address you can use the `Get-NetAdapter` cmdlet.

```
$adapter = Get-NetAdapter
$adapter.MacAddress
```

You can correlate the two pieces of information using the InterfaceIndex. Then return a hashtable that makes each accessible.  The following creates an array of these combined objects.

```
$combined = Get-NetIPConfiguration | ForEach-Object {
    $adapter = Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex $_.InterfaceIndex
    @{ IP = $_; Adapter = $adapter }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but requires V3 and Windows 8 or higher - a lot of corporate environments are still Windows 7 and V2...

Comment: I don't see mac in there.  It did work on Win7, though.  It has a DeviceID, though not sure what that is and not sure how to access it either.

Comment: Updated answer to include the mac address.

Comment: The difficulty that I am having with the information split for each adapter across two variables is in merging them into one object so that each mac address is with the correct adapter.  What is the best way to merge objects like this?

Comment: Also, is there an attribute which says which adapter is currently in use?

Comment: Added code which correlates the two.  I'm not sure if there is anything to say the adapter is in use.  Try dumping the adapter contents with `$adapter | Select *` to view all of its associated data.

Comment: I tried `$adapter | Select *` and I didn't see anything there.

Comment: When you say "in use" do you mean currently sending packets or what? Please clarify.

Comment: I mean `netconnectionstatus` from `get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter`.  And I am interested in exactly what that means because you are right that any adapter can send packets at any time if they are connected.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, if you want (1) an object and (2) something that should work in older versions of PowerShell, is to pull the network information using WMI:

```
$adapters = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration

$adapters | Format-Table Description,IPAddress,MACAddress

$enabled = $adapters | Where-Object{$_.IPEnabled -eq $true}
```

You can use the following to explore the full set of data that you get per adapter:

```
$enabled | Format-List *
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull data out of strings (with regexes) and assign to variables, I think what you are looking for are **named capture groups**, which you can use in a manner similar to the following:

```
(?<word1>\w+)
```

Then you can pull these out of the `$matches` hashtable by name, for example:

```
PS> "hello world!" -match '(?<word1>\w+)'
True

PS> $matches["word1"]
hello
```

You can have multiple named capture groups in the same regex, but each one will need to have distinct names. Armed with this you should be able to match the various bits of text you want and give them names to be picked up easily afterwards.

The following blog talks about this concept a little more:

- http://tasteofpowershell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/named-groups-in-regular-expressions.html

Comment: The following command does not produce true/false or any matches: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> 
$ip -match "(?<lan_name>Ethernet adapter) (?<lan_name2>Local[^:]+):\n* +(?<lan_msg>([^\n]+\n)*)"
The following produce no results:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $matches["lan_msg"]

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ip

Comment: I replaced "\n" with "\r\n" and removed " +" to get:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ip -match "(?<lan_name>Ethernet adapter) (?<lan_name2>Local[^:]+):(\r\n)*(?<lan_msg>([^\r\n]+\r\n)*)"
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:  .. still no results for: $matches.lan_name

Comment: I don't see true or false from either: $ip -match "\r"  OR  $ip -match "\n"  I think the new line codes are the issue but I can't figure out which code to use.  regex101 is happy with \n but Powershell is not.

Comment: Given that $ip is multi-line, you may want to try looping through each line with a `foreach` statement: `foreach($line in $ip){...}`. You can match `$line` and build up your results as you go.

Comment: Please guide me through how this foreach approach works and how I would build up my results.  Since I haven't defined $line, what happens when $line in $ip is specified?  How do I build the results in each section into an object separated by section?  Given that my regex for $lan_name, etc. is not working, how do I figure out why not and match the correct line characters with the regex?

Comment: Please read this: [about_Foreach](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847816.aspx)

Comment: The `foreach($line in $ip)` part will define the variable `$line` and loop through the (multi-line) text in `$ip`, updating `$line` each time. This allows you to deal with the content one line at a time with a block of commands. You could then try to match each line against different Regexes, and deal with different matches one-by-one. Example to follow...

Comment: `$Output = ""; 
foreach($line in $ip){
  if($line -match "Description.*:(?<Description>.*)"){
    $Output+=$matches['Description'].Trim()
  }
}`

Comment: Your code seems to look through the entire ipconfig for the regex Description and then store the extraction in Output regardless of in which adapter the match was found.  Is that correct?  I assume similar regex would be created to capture each attribute like subnet, gateway, etc.  Could your code keep the attributes for each adapter in separate objects? It seems like the attributes of each adapter would be meshed together with that code.  Is there a need or a way to iterate through each line in ipconfig and keep the adapter organization?

Comment: By recommending the use of foreach, are you suggesting that ipconfig is returning an array of lines and not pure text with \r\n demarking each line?  Added:  I think that it may be an array.  Running: $ip.GetType(), returns:BaseType: System.Array  Now I have to figure out how to deal with arrays of this type.

Comment: In short, yes... while you are looping though each line you can pull out whatever text you find matched in that line (potentially with multiple regex tests) and add to different variables. To be frank, though, this whole business of looping through lines of text is a hard way to go about pulling out network interface details; there are a couple of other answers on this thread that solve that problem more directly. What we're really discussing here is the more general problem of looping though muti-line text (i.e. an array of strings) and pulling out various bits of information.

Comment: There must be dozens of ways to do this, of which this example (initiate empty array(s), loop through text, add interesting bits to the array(s)). If you want to build up more complex output objects that my example, then I suggest you research creating custom objects too.

Comment: Charlie, you are correct that some very good answers get us part of what I am looking for, and that this is more of an exercise in creating nested objects from arrays.  I still have difficulty with both the `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` and the `Get-NetIPConfiguration`.  The wmi issue is in getting the information from the various objects into a single nested object.  I think the `Get-NetIPConfiguration` option looks cleaner but it lacks the desired nested object structure and it lacks current active adapter information.  For learning, I want to know all 3 methods.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output of IPCONFIG /ALL, it looks like there are 3 different types of data being returned - the header section at the beginning and the an arbitrary number of sections for active and inactive adapters, each with a different format and set of data returned.

Here is a set of regular expressions that can be used to parse each one, and capture the values presented:

```
$Header_Regex = 
@'
(?m)Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : (.*)
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : (.*)
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : (.*)

'@


$Active_Adapter_Regex  =
@'
(?m)(.+? adapter .+):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : (.*)
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : (.*)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : (.*) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : (.*)
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ((?:.|\n)*)
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : (.*)
'@

$Inactive_Adapter_Regex = 
@'
(?m)(.+? adapter .+):

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : (.*)
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : (.*)
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : (.*)

'@

$Cmd_Output = (ipconfig /all | out-string) 

$header = 
if ($Cmd_Output -match $Header_Regex)
  {$matches}

$Inactive_Adapters = 
[regex]::Matches($Cmd_Output,$Inactive_Adapter_Regex) 

$Active_Adapters =
[regex]::Matches($Cmd_Output,$Active_Adapter_Regex)
```

chew on that a bit, and let me know if that's making any sense.

Comment: Excellent code, great idea with out-string, and lots of questions:  1) Why does the regex start on the next line without using ``` and what does the `@'` do?  2) I see that `.GetType` returns Name:MatchCollection, but why does `.count` return 1?  Is there only one match and how do I access the other matches?  3) I see parathensis creating un-named capture groups in the regex.  Is there a way to use them?  4) What is the purpose of `(?:.|\n)*` under the DNS Servers section?  5) Why use the if statement for the headers instead of the Matches for the adapters?  [more...]

Comment: ... 6)  Is `[regex]` specifying that the result of Matches is regex?   How does Matches work?

Comment: Read get-help about_quoting_rules for an explanation of the here string (@'...'@).  See get-help about_automatic_variables for an explanation of $matches.